# Error inserting multiple data formats in a database with my sql using a loop

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm really new in this programming world, I'm working on a project where I need to extract some values from an API and insert them into a SQL base , also I need to figure out how to only add values beyond the last date in the database, right now I have this block of code and I'm getting this error message

```
   def datodolar():
        pagina = urlopen("https://apis.datos.gob.ar/series/api/series/?ids=168.1_T_CAMBIOR_D_0_0_26&start_date=2018-07&limit=5000")
        json_str = pagina.read().decode("utf8")


        return json.loads(json_str)


    historicodolar=datodolar()


    valoresdolar = historicodolar["data"]
    #for values in valoresdolar:
        #print(values[1])

    dateforuse= datetime.now()    

    for values in valoresdolar:



        objStr = datetime.strftime(dateforuse, '%Y-%m-%d')
        objStr3 = datetime.strptime(values[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
        objStr2 = datetime.strftime(objStr3, '%Y-%m-%d')


        #print(fecha, "  ---->  ", objDate,"  ---->  ",objStr)

        sql =("INSERT INTO dolar (fechadato,tipo_cambio,fechacarga) VALUES (%s, %s,%s)", (objStr2, values[1],objStr))
        #"insert into dolar(fechadato,tipo_cambio,fechacarga) values ('"+(objStr3)+"','"(values)[1]+"','"+(objStr)+"')"


        #print(sql)
        cursor.execute(sql)

    conexion.commit()
```

The error message is

sql ="insert into dolar(fechadato,tipo_cambio,fechacarga) values ('"+str(objStr3)+"','"(values)[1]+"','"+str(objStr)+"')"
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I tried a couple of different ways to insert the values in the database but with both get different error messages.

Thanks so much for any hint about how to solve this.

Comment: The form you have active is correct. **NEVER** use string-concatenation to form queries, that's a [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you're getting errors, please tell us exactly what the error says.

Comment: *"NEVER use string-concatenation to form queries, that's a SQL injection hole"* uhm @tadman string-concatenation to form queries does not always automatic mean it is prone to SQL injections if you construct `INSERT INTO .... VALUES(%s, %s,%s). (%s, %s,%s)`  for example with string concatenation and use prepared statements correctly to match those variables it is still safe if you get mine point here.. Well yes you risk a SQL injection more easy that is what i can agree on when using string-concatenation if you don't know what you are doing..

Comment: @tadman thanks for the advice , this is the error message ql ="insert into dolar(fechadato,tipo_cambio,fechacarga) values ('"+str(objStr3)+"','"(values)[1]+"','"+str(objStr)+"')" TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: `str()` doesn't belong here. Use the advice Raymond is giving where you use `%s` and bind with one or more tuples instead. `str()` is **extremely dangerous** in this context because it allows not only data, but entire SQL statements to be shoved in there.